# VS Code is not recognising basic functions in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[Here .loc command used often in pandas library is not recognised but it is working fine when the code is running, how to fix this issue?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJu8b.png)

Comment: If you restart VS Code it may fix the issue.

Comment: Enough information to answer a question needs to be included _in the question itself_, **as text**. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: If this is about IntelliSense, establishing exactly _which_ IntelliSense warning this is and what source it comes from would be a place to start in asking a stronger question. An error coming from pep-8 analysis is different from an error coming from pyflakes analysis, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the code works correctly and there is an underline warning, this is usually the prompt message given by **linting**.

You can use the **PROBLEMS** panel to see where your code is out of specification and see what is giving error messages.

In general, you can get rid of these underscore warnings by turning off linting or switching between different lints.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- `Python: Enable/Disable Linting` --> `Disable`

  [image]
- `Python: Select Linter`

  [image]

It is also possible to add parameters to ignore specific warnings for the currently enabled linter.

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--disable=C0111"
]
```